# Ruby DNSSD Bonjour IP address discovery

Tags: ruby, sockets, bonjour, dns-sd

BACKGROUND

I am trying to use Ruby DNSSD to discover the IP address of a few devices.

My code will correctly discover the NAME of the devices.  I tried to access the devices using the NAME.local.   I have tried this method: https://github.com/jmitchener/ruby-dnssd-test/blob/master/main.rb

- How do I find their IP address? Or
- Access those devices using the hostname?

UPDATE

I proved to my self that my theory that the Socket command is not searching past the /etc/hosts file

I manually aded my three redeye units to the /etc/hosts file and was able to resolve the IP address.

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.69.77   RedEye_B0105-92646.local.
192.168.69.75   RedEye_E0103-85245.local.
192.168.69.76   RedEye_B0104-99552.local.
```

code

```
  @@reIP = Hash.new
  DNSSD.browse '_tf_redeye._tcp' do |reply|
    puts reply.name
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(reply.name + ".local.", nil, Socket::AF_INET)
    @@reIP[reply.name] = addr
    puts @@reIP
  end
```

output

```
RedEye_B0105-92646
{"RedEye_B0105-92646"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 3, 0]]}
RedEye_E0103-85245
{"RedEye_B0105-92646"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 3, 0]], "RedEye_E0103-85245"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 3, 0]]}
RedEye_B0104-99552
{"RedEye_B0105-92646"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.77", "192.168.69.77", 2, 3, 0]], "RedEye_E0103-85245"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 3, 0]], "RedEye_B0104-99552"=>[["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 1, 6], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "192.168.69.76", "192.168.69.76", 2, 3, 0]]}
```

The question now is why is the Socket command not searching past the /etc/hosts file for IP resolution
1. AVAHI and/or DNSSD is not caching the address as they are reports by the DNSSD.browse, possible a configuration setting
2. I do not have a mDNS server installed or configured properly
3. Something else is conflicting, like DNSMASQ

Answer (score 0):

The results from a DNS-SD browse operation are DNS-SD service names, not hostnames.

To get from a service name to a connection you need to start a DNS-SD resolve operation using the service name, service domain  (do not hardcode ".local") and interface number (if the Ruby wrapper supplies it) exactly as supplied to the browse callback.

If the resolve operation is successful it will return the service's hostname, port (which may not be the well-known port) and a set of key-value pairs containing meta information (service-specific) which you can then use to establish the connection.

EDIT:

Put another way, you've not done [this part](https://github.com/jmitchener/ruby-dnssd-test/blob/master/main.rb#L19-L27) of the example you linked.

Answer (score 0):

I intentionally hard coded appending the `.local.` to the name in the course of troubleshooting. I removed and reinstalled avahi and the dnssd gem my code now resolves the IP address without having the hosts defined in the `/etc/hosts` file. I now get exactly what I wanted, a hash with just the names and IP addresses.

Code

```
  @@reIP = Hash.new
  DNSSD.browse '_tf_redeye._tcp.' do |reply|
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(reply.name + ".local.", nil, Socket::AF_INET)
    @@reIP[reply.name] = addr[0][2]
  end
```

Resulting hash

```
{"RedEye_B0105-92646"=>"192.168.69.77", "RedEye_B0104-99552"=>"192.168.69.76", "RedEye_E0103-85245"=>"192.168.69.75"}
```

Comment: You're still using a service name (`reply.name`) as a hostname. If that works it is coincidental. I've cribbed together a Ruby [example](https://gist.github.com/andrewtj/d7e5de756dd177489ee2) to try and make what I'm saying more clear.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case, I'm only interested in discovering one particular target the name for which is not likely to change, so I'm not concerned about hard coding the domain.  Previously, I tried to access the device using the target, but it did not work.  I will give it another try now that socket is resolving the IP address.

Comment: My application doesn't support access via the target name.

Comment: It's not just about the domain. If you've run the example, you've seen a service name like " * SlashDot, News for Nerds, Stuff that Matters" show up and be resolved to slashdot.org.:80. The point being to illustrate that a service's name and a service's hostname aren't connected. Don't slap ".local." on the end of a service name and expect to get something you can plug into getaddrinfo() with any reliability.